# Using case statement before order by clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by, case-statement

I would like to have a condition statement before Order By.

In my below query there is chance for Marks to be null, in that case I would like to Order by Rank Asc

```
SELECT TOP 1 P.[Score]
FROM dbo.[Profile] P
WHERE P.[ProfileId] = @ProfileId
ORDER BY P.[Marks] DESC AS [ProfileScore]
```

I tried changing it to the below way but it’s giving a compile error

```
SELECT TOP 1 P.[Score]
FROM dbo.[Profile] P
WHERE P.[ProfileId] = @ProfileId 
ORDER BY 
    (CASE WHEN P.[Marks] IS NOT NULL THEN P.[Marks] END) DESC,
    (CASE WHEN P.[Marks] IS NULL THEN P.[Rank] END) ASC AS [ProfileScore]
```

But it gives an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DESC'

Comment: `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*. Please show us the error. Remove "AS [ProfileScore]" from the order by, you don't alias order by terms.

Comment: Unless ALL of the marks in your table are NULL then your original query will still sort the data by the highest mark to the lowest and then select only the top 1 row.   Also as @Dale mentions, remove the ```AS [ProfileScore]```.

Comment: There is a `AS [ProfileScore]` too many in your `ORDER BY`. You cannot create aliases in `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Hi Dale,  When I execute the query it says InCorrect syntax near the keyword ‘DESC’ , How do I alias my P.[Score] ?

Comment: You create column aliases in the `SELECT` clause. Are you saying that there exists no column `[Score]` in your table? Or do you simply want to give it another display name?

Comment: Why are you trying to alias it? Its only used in the order by clause, an alias has no meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an `AS [ProfileScore]` too many in your `ORDER BY`. You cannot create aliases in `ORDER BY`.

If both `Marks` and `Rank` are numeric, I suggest:

```
SELECT TOP 1 P.[Score]
FROM dbo.[Profile] P
WHERE P.[ProfileId] = @ProfileId 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN P.[Marks] IS NULL THEN P.[Rank] ELSE -P.[Marks] END;
```